# Eliminating whitespace from hidden elements while printing from browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a report page in my project where am showing a stylish table with the help of a javascript plugin. Here is the sample code...

```
 <div class="stylish_table">
   <table>
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

and the javascript trigger is...

```
 $('.stylish_table table').stylishTable();
```

this is generating a stylish table which has a fixed height and the data is scrollable for a comfortable view. Now when i wanted to print this page the page also printing as same as it looked in the browser. But i want only the table to be printed with all its data spreading over many sheets.

So i searched ways to "stop the javascript trigger when it is printing" so that table will not get styled and print the normal one. But none of the solutions i found worked. So i followed a way to generate the same table twice and write media query to hide one on print.

I mean the following...

```
 <div class="stylish_table hide_for_print">
   <table>
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
   </table>
 </div>

   <table class="hide_for_screen">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
   </table>
```

in css i add...

```
  <style>
     @media print
     { .hide_for_print{ display:none; } }
      @media screen
     { .hide_for_screen{ display:none; } }
  </style>
```

It is working as expected but with one issue. When i print it is making the empty space of that element which is being hide. whatever i put inside hide_for_print is hiding from print but a empty blank space is printing instead.

How do i hide from print and also avoid the blank space ?

Comment: I haven't tested this, nor do I have the means to test it, but have you tried using `visibility: hidden;` in conjunction with `display: none;`?

Comment: i used only display none... i will also try visibility hidden...

Comment: let me know if it works so I can post it as an answer.

Comment: no it did not worked...

Comment: Just to confirm, it is being properly hidden from browser view?

Comment: no... it is behaving proper except making empty space on its location when it is being printed...